# Node + Nginx reverse proxy never works

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've spent so much time trying to get this work that it's cutting into actual development time. I'm trying to set up two domains on my site `example.com` and `example2.com` but navigating to the domain in browser results in a 502 at best.

The `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that I got from a friend:

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;


events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The `etc/nginx/sites-available/sites` that I also got from a friend:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    # proxy pass to nodejs
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
}
server {
    server_name example2.com;
    # proxy pass to nodejs
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }
}
```

I've been working in circles and have tried so many different configurations that all fail, this specific one results in a Gateway error 502 for both sites.

I've never been able to get this to work and I have no idea why, A second set of eyes would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that looks wrong in your nginx configuration. If the Node server to which nginx is trying to forward a connection is not actually listening on the port you specify in your configuration you will get a 502 status code.

To verify whether it is listening correctly, you can use any tool that can connect to a port to perform an HTTP GET. So, for instance:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:9001/
```

Or `wget` could also be used for this. If the connection is refused chances are that your node server is not running at all or configured to listen on a different port.

Comment: Oh that was it! The node server error'd and closed without me noticing. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'm doing to delete my comments on your question since they are not useful anymore.